# Issue with setInterval(), function not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

UPDATED FUNCTION:

```
 <script>
        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache : false
        });

        function getMessage() {
            $.get("php/getMessage.php?q=1" + "&" + Date.now(), function(data) {
                $("#typed").typed({
                    strings : [data],
                    typeSpeed : 30,
                    contentType : 'html',
                });
            });
        };
        setInterval(getMessage, 5000);

</script>
```

PREVIOUS VERSION:

```
function getMessage() {
    $.get("php/getMessage.php?q=1", function(data) {
        $("#typed").typed({
            strings : [data],
            typeSpeed : 30,
            contentType : 'html',
        });
    });
};
setInterval(getMessage(), 5000);
```

So this is where my problem appears to lie.

Initially, the data is pulled from the database (through getMessage.php) perfectly and is written to the page as expected.

I am sure it is probably something so ridiculously simple but I am completely stumped as to why this isn't then recalling every 5 seconds and pulling an updated value from the table.

I'd appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you add the typed function to your post?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what information you need. The top of the post is the function being performed and then recalled.

Comment: Yes, you call a function within that function called typed() , can you please post that function also.

Comment: Ah... it is external to the site [here](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/blob/master/js/typed.js)

Comment: change url to ["php/getMessage.php?q=1" + "&" + Date.now()]

Comment: I still get no update from those changes... I am showing my current code in the edit of the original post.

Answer (score 4):

```
setInterval(getMessage(), 5000);
```

You are calling the function and then passing the returned value to `setInterval`. What you actually want to do is passing the **function** to `setInterval()`

```
setInterval(getMessage, 5000);
```

Comment: I have tried that and the only thing it seems to have achieved for me is delaying the initial output 5 seconds. New data is not then pulled from the database.

Comment: The answer is fine.Just turn off the cache setting of ajax or add a random param in url.

Comment: Still no luck in the above, I have also now tried appending a delay function with a callback to the getMessage function which does not seem to be achieving anything

Answer (score -2):

As with tkausl's answer, you also have the option of calling

```
setInterval(function(){getMessage()}, 5000);
```

However it is longer so it comes down to personal preference.

Comment: unfortunately, this does exactly the same as the above, delays the initial call for 5 seconds and does not then recall the function.